# Sitecore AB Page test setup issue - Test combination does not match the test definition

Tags: content-testing

I'm trying to setup a A/B page test in Sitecore 8.2 Update 5 and when I start the test, I see the below error message and the page blows up.

```
Exception: System.InvalidOper1tionException
Message: Test combination does not match the test definition
Source: Sitecore.ContentTesting
   at Sitecore.ContentTesting.Models.TestCombination.GetValue(Int32 variableIndex)
   at Sitecore.ContentTesting.Pipelines.EvaluateTestExposureBase`1.ValidateCombinationDatasource(TestCombination combination, ITestConfiguration testConfiguration)
   at Sitecore.ContentTesting.Pipelines.EvaluateTestExposureBase`1.Process(TPipelineArgs args)
   at (Object , Object[] )
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain)
   at Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.PipelineService.RunPipeline[TArgs](String pipelineName, TArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Mvc.Routing.RouteHttpHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext context, AsyncCallback cb, Object extraData)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

Have anyone faced this issue in the past? Any ideas or thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I contacted Sitecore support and the issue is when the A/B test is not fully published from CM to CD servers. They provided a [patch](https://sitecore.box.com/s/gzxiqyw5v2rp1u4oivswkozvqc1dt52l) which resolved the issue.