# The site always displays the latest version of the item that is under the page test

Tags: content-testing, experience-optimization

I created and started a page test in Experience Optimization in Sitecore. During the test creation I created a new version of item that I was going to test. Then I moved the new version of item to the Approved workflow state and publish this item with related items and subitems. And every time I open the page with test in browser (always in a new window in incognito mode) I see the latest version of this item and never the other versions under test. I get item from Sitecore to display it by the means of `Sitecore.Context.Database.GetItem(ID)`. Any suggestions why it  is always displayed the latest version and users never can see the other versions that are under the page test.

Comment: Which version of Sitecore are you on?

Comment: @MarkCassidy i'm on Sitecore 8.2

Comment: Did you check this question?  It tells of a bug in 8.2 that needs a hotfix related to page testing. https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/13128/sitecore-ab-page-test-setup-issue-test-combination-does-not-match-the-test-def?rq=1

Comment: @MarkCassidy but I don't have any errors with my page test